# Clicking a grid item causes that item to drop far below my mouse pointer

Tags: html, css, react-grid-layout

I am trying to learn react-grid-layout but I couldn't fixed this problem. When I try to drag a grid it moves right of my cursor also every grid renders at the middle in the beginning.

I want to make a layout like in this example [Here](https://react-grid-layout.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/1-basic.html)

[image]

**Here you can see the demonstration of my problem.**

[image]

**The code that I use is below** and this is the css for the grid [styles_grid.css](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/blob/master/css/styles.css)

```
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";
import "./react_grid_layout/styles_grid.css";
import "./react_grid_layout/styles.resize.css";

function Dashboard(props) {
  return (
    <GridLayout className="layout" cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>
      <div className="bg-white" key="a" data-grid={{ x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 }}>
        a
      </div>
      <div className="bg-white" key="b" data-grid={{ x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2 }}>
        b
      </div>
      <div className="bg-white" key="c" data-grid={{ x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 }}>
        c
      </div>
    </GridLayout>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem we need to add `style={{ alignItems: "start" }}` to
`<GridLayout ...>`

Comment: I dont think your approach is correct, Because withour adding this css grid works fine. Have you included `react-grid-layout` css in your code ?

Comment: Yes I included it. But it seems that something happens in my code without it and makes the layout like on the screenshot that I added. Not sure what happens on the code.

Comment: Create a codesandbox demo and share a link, I will check.